# CodingBat (Strings-2 starOut) Trouble with Strings

Tags: java, string

Question:
Return a version of the given string, where for every star (*) in the string the star and the chars immediately to its left and right are gone. So "ab*cd" yields "ad" and "ab**cd" also yields "ad". 
Ex.
    starOut("ab*cd") → "ad"
    starOut("ab***cd") → "ad"
    starOut("smeilly") → "silly"

I know there are answers online but I don't want to copy them. I have started with most of it but do not know how to take out the spaces and convert back to a string? Also if you guys have a better solution feel free to provide that.  Please don't provide Regex based solutions.

```
public static String starOut(String str) {
    char[] array = str.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == '*' && i != 0) {
            if(array[i - 1] != '*') {
                array[i - 1] = ' ';
            }
            if(array[i + 1] != '*') {
                array[i + 1] = ' ';
            }
        }
        //Rest of Code...
        if()
    }
   return str;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example string with the result you are trying to create.

Comment: @GregoryBasior I just edited in the question and examples sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your code and then just loop through the array and append it to a StringBuilder.

However this will be problematic if the input can contain a **space**, as we simply ignore all the whitespace. If the input can contain whitespace consider setting the char to something else, or perhaps use the object Character so you can set it to null.

```
public static String starOut(String str) {
    char[] array = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i] == '*') {
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && array[i - 1] != '*')
                array[i - 1] = ' ';
            if (i + 1 < array.length && array[i + 1] != '*')
                array[i + 1] = ' ';
            array[i] = ' ';
        }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : array)
        if (c != ' ')
            sb.append(c);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: it still return a null string and I added the complete question and some examples if that clears up some stuff.